# How do i initialize a slice for future assignment?

Tags: go, slice

```golang
greetslice := []string{
        "Hello, %v. Welcome to the world!",
        "Come on %v Explore.",
        "You are very welcome here %v!",
    }
```

What if I want to do it this way...

```golang
var greetslice []string

greetslice = {
    "Hello, %v. Welcome to the world!",
    "Come on %v Explore.",
    "You are very welcome here %v!",
}
```

But the following error occurs.

```
# greetings
../greetings/greetings.go:29:15: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression
../greetings/greetings.go:35:2: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

How do I initialize the slice first and assign it some values later correctly?

Comment: You can declare the slice with capacity and can add data to it when required. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assignment:

```
greetslice = {
    "Hello, %v. Welcome to the world!",
    "Come on %v Explore.",
    "You are very welcome here %v!",
}
```

Is invalid. The [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) must include the type:

```
greetslice = []string{
    "Hello, %v. Welcome to the world!",
    "Come on %v Explore.",
    "You are very welcome here %v!",
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-VeHodhlCzn).

Another option is to use the builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function to append values to a slice which may even be `nil`:

```
greetslice = append(greetslice,
    "Hello, %v. Welcome to the world!",
    "Come on %v Explore.",
    "You are very welcome here %v!",
)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SuEy1RKKMNF).

Also note that if you know how many elements you will add, you can initialize your slice with 0 length and sufficient capacity, which may speed up the further append operations:

```
var greetslice = make([]string, 0, 3) // room for 3 elements to append later
```